# Will Xamarin app run on windows phone?

Tags: c#, xamarin, handheld

What is the best way to write for iPhone, Android and Windows phone ?  If I'm writing in C# and using Xamarin will my app run on the windows phone as well ?

Comment: Yes planning on VS not Mono develop, I guess it's a crap question seeing the down votes.

Comment: You'll have to write the app for Windows Phone.  I don't think you can reuse either the android or iPhone code - at least not for the UI.  If you have class libraries supporting the application, those should be able to be reused across the platforms.

Comment: Though now [see Xamarin Forms](https://xamarin.com/forms). You can write a decent simple, cross platform UI in Forms using XAML and friends.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can share any code written with the [BCLs that are included with Xamarin](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/assemblies/) (or any library built on top of those).

You will then need to write a custom Windows Phone application that uses those libraries. It is easiest to think of this as the "UI" of your application. You cannot share UI code between iOS, Android, and Windows Phone.

The [MWC app](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/building_cross_platform_applications/) is probably the best example of how to architect a solution that spans the 3 platforms.

Comment: How naive of me, I just read on the Xaramin website about cross platform and didn't realize the GUI needs different code for each of the platforms.  Thanks for clearing that up and actually answering the question instead of down-voting like others did.  Now I'm setup in the VM and can start playing with it.

Comment: There is a russian startup bringing XAML from Windows to Android/iOS via Xamarin. So basically you can write even UI once and run on all 3 platforms. But I have no experience with it at all.